# The #selector is not compatible with the closure?

Tags: swift, closures, selector, func

I have tried to implement the custom function with the closure. But it's does not supported by `#selector`.

Here's an example:

```
class Core: NSObject {

    static let shared:Core = Core.init()


    func button(viewController: UIViewController, button: UIButton, title: String, color: UIColor, completion: () -> Void) {

        button.layer.cornerRadius = button.bounds.width / 2
        button.setTitle(title, for: .normal)
        button.setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: .normal)
        button.backgroundColor = color
        button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 18)
        button.addTarget(viewController, action: #selector(completion()), for: .touchUpInside)
    }
}
```

The Xcode gives me a build time issue:

> Argument of '#selector' does not refer to an '@objc' method, property, or initializer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A selector is a string that's used to identify methods, properties, initializers in the Objective C runtime. When you use a notation like `#selector(SomeClass.SomeMethod(withParam:AndParam:)`, you're specifying the selector in a format that the compiler can parse easily and verify to be correct. But ultimately, that would just be reduced down into a C string like: `"SomeMethodwithParam:AndParam:"`.

Essentially, every class has a dictionary which maps selectors to the function pointers of the code that implements them. When a selector is used to invoke a function, the Objective C runtime searches the method table for the class in question, and looks up the method implementation corresponding to the given selector.

There's no way for this process to work with closures, which are anonymous by definition. Thus, you can only use selectors to refer to methods, properties, initializers that are registered with the Objective C runtime (which is what `@objc` does, implicitly or explicitly).

Answer (score 2):

You can not call a completion block in this way. A `#selector` is a defined function in a class somewhere in your project. A closure is not a valid selector.

Declare your completion block as a `typealias` and store the completion as a property of your class. Then you will want to call this completion from a defined function:

```
// Declare your completion as typealias
typealias YourCompletion = () -> Void

// At top of your class
var completion: YourCompletion?

// Then in your function declare the completion: parameter to be of type YourCompletion
func button(viewController: UIViewController, button: UIButton, title: String, color: UIColor, completion: YourCompletion) {

    // Assign completion as property
    self.completion = completion

    // Configure your button
    button.layer.cornerRadius = button.bounds.width / 2
    button.setTitle(title, for: .normal)
    button.setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: .normal)
    button.backgroundColor = color
    button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 18)

    // Have your button action be the function you'll make below
    button.addTarget(viewController, action: #selector(self.callCompletion), for: .touchUpInside)
}

func callCompletion() {
    if let completion = self.completion {
        // Call completion
        completion()
    }
}
```

Comment: Using a property to store the completion handler like this is ***really*** fragile. It's not thread safe and it's prone to state errors

Comment: Yes this is obviously a simple quick answer to @Mannopson question. Some manual checking against the current thread would be useful in a multithreading situation. Or just stay on the main thread and you'll be fine. But for starters this will get Mannopson in the right direction.

Comment: I disagree, this certainly not the right direction. This is a dangerous approach in the hands of somebody who might not fully comprehend the pitfalls. If you really want to crowbar closures into ObjC apis, then the only way I can think of is to instantiate a new class, and register the closure bodies as methods with unique selectors.

Comment: @Alexander +1 you are most certainly welcome to disagree and include your solution to the question. My answer illustrates how to call a closure in the manner in which the question was asked. Should Mannopson have been asking the question in the first place? That is a different issue.