# Alternative to closure-style to execute code in UI thread

Tags: ios, swift, ui-thread

From background thread, when UI needs to be updated, it needs to post to DispatchQueue.main using the [async(execute:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchqueue/2016103-async) function, as shown below:

```
static func executeInUIThread(_ uiThreadFunc: @escaping (Any?) -> Void, _ parms: Any?) {
  DispatchQueue.main.async {
    // Update UI 
    uiThreadFunc(parms)
  }
}
```

It is possible to access `uiThreadFunc` and `parms` inside the closure because [closures capture variables from their 'surrounding context'](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/documentation/the-swift-programming-language/closures/#Capturing-Values).

But let's say, I don't like the lambda-style (called closures in swift) of programming. How can I do this without closures?

I attempted the following:

```
static func executeInUIThread(_ uiThreadFunc: @escaping (Any?) -> Void, _ parms: Any?) {
  let workItem = DispatchWorkItem(block: EventLoopMgr.InternalExecuteInUIThread)

  DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: workItem)
}

private static func InternalExecuteInUIThread() {
  // How to execute the uiThreadfunc? This block doesn't take any parameters.
}
```

It doesn't work because, the [block](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchworkitem/2300102-init) when initialising the DispatchWorkItem takes no parameters. Therefore, I can't pass `uiThreadFunc` and `parms` to this block.

I can store the `uiThreadFunc` and `parms` as static variables, but then it needs to be made multi-thread friendly.

Is there an easier way to execute in UIThread using DispatchQueue.main but without using closures?

Comment: No.  Use a closure.

Comment: You can pass `uiThreadFunc` as the `block` parameter, but it will still probably be a closure where you call `executeInUIThread` since that is how you are going to be able to operate on the local context.

Comment: What specific thing about closures do you not like?

Comment: @Sweeper, In the project I'm working on, it's a convention not to have anonymous blocks of code in the middle of the function. It doesn't depict the natural flow of execution, as closures are executed after the current function... most of the time.

Comment: So a *named* block would satisfy you? You can declare `func someName() { uiThreadFunc(parms) }` and then pass `someName` to `main.async`.

Comment: Or, you can declare a helper function `helper` that creates a `() -> Void` given a `(T) -> Void` and a `T`. The helper function would return a closure. Then you can call `main.async(helper(uiThreadFunc, parms))`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In the project I'm working on, it's a convention not to have anonymous blocks of code in the middle of the function. It doesn't depict the natural flow of execution

Okay, so you can make this *not* anonymous:

```
// I made this generic for you :)
func executeInUIThread<T>(_ uiThreadFunc: @escaping (T) -> Void, _ parms: T) {
    func helper() {
        uiThreadFunc(parms)
    }
    DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: helper)
}
```

Here I gave the name `helper` to the block of code that will be run on the main queue.

Technically, a local function still counts as a closure according to the [Swift Guide](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/documentation/the-swift-programming-language/closures), but if all you want to avoid is an "anonymous" block of code, using a local function definitely achieves that.

If the local function is too much noise, you can move it out of `executeInUIThread` like this:

```
func partiallyApply<T>(_ arg: T, to function: (T) -> Void) -> () -> Void {
    func helper() { function(arg) }
    return helper
}
```

Then you can just do:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: partiallyApply(parms, to: uiThreadFunc))
```

which arguably is more readable. You

Answer (score 1):

Will this be helpful for you?

`test` to trigger it and `updateView` is one example of your `uiThreadFunc`

```
func test() {
    let aFunc = #selector(updateView)
    let success = executeInUIThread(caller: self, uiThreadFunc: aFunc, "xxx")
}

func executeInUIThread(caller: NSObject, uiThreadFunc: Selector, _ parms: Any?) -> Bool {
    if caller.responds(to: uiThreadFunc) {
        caller.performSelector(onMainThread: uiThreadFunc, with: parms, waitUntilDone: false)
        return true
    } else {
        return false
    }
}

@objc func updateView(param: String) { }
```

---

For more Info, please
have a check [GCD vs performSelector](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19501548/17771995)

Comment: I need to pass 2 parameters - `uiThreadFunc` and `parms`. I cannot define the `uiThreadFunc` myself. According to [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/nsobject/1414900-performselector), selector 'points' to a method with one or zero arguments.

Comment: It [seems](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43485387) selectors can't refer to closures. It has to be a top-level function.